# How would you determine $\sin(x) = -\cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can pretty much look at the equation and say the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi k$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4} + 2\pi k$ (where $k \in \mathbb N$) but how can I show work for this?

Comment: Note that your two cases can be condensed into just one : $\frac{3\pi}{4} + k \pi$.

Answer (score 8):

Divide both sides by $\cos x$ to get $\tan x = -1$.

Comment: Oh wow I should have seen that. Thank you

Comment: @DavidJones No problem :)

Comment: You're tacitly using the fact that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are never simultaneously zero.

Comment: I find it best practice to avoid dividing by functions to solve equations. It can lead to a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @Almentoe I also agree with you as sometimes division may eliminate solutions so I would normally advocate for factoring, but in this case, as the Guest above mentioned, the functions do not share a root so the equations solutions are "conserved".

Answer (score 6):

This may be overkill, but it could be useful in different situations, for instance something like $\sin x=-\cos3x$.

Recall that $-\cos x=\sin(x-\pi/2)$ so your equation becomes
$$
\sin x=\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
This amounts to saying that either
$$
x-\frac{\pi}{2}=x+2k\pi
$$
(which has no solutions) or
$$
x-\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi-x+2k\pi
$$
that becomes
$$
2x=\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$
and, finally,
$$
x=\frac{3}{4}\pi+k\pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

or we divide by $\sin(x)$ and we get $$\cot(x)=-1$$

Comment: I'm not sure this adds to the discussion, it is similar in content to Jeevan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, so +1. Joel Cohen's idea is good, it is always a good idea to reduce the amount of work one needs to do.

Another way of answering it (that shows understanding of the periodic properties of trig functions) is by noting $$\sin(x + k\pi) = (-1)^k \sin(x)$$ and $$ \cos(x + k\pi) = (-1)^k \cos(x).$$

The above facts mean that we only need to seek solutions (to your equation) $a$, where $ 0 \leq a < \pi$. The only solution in this range is $\frac{ 3\pi}{4}$.

So some solutions are: $ \frac{3\pi}{4} + k \pi $, for any $k$, an integer. They are in fact all the solutions, as the trig functions are $2\pi$ periodic.